# how to make the same project solution work on both visual studio 2015 and 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using Microsoft visual studio 2015 and my friend using visual studio 2017, we both are working on single c++ project, if i take his code into my studio it shows errors,

I want the same solution and same project file into my MSVS 2015 but he has version 141 and I have v140,

Is there any way to **make the same project solution work on both visual studio 2015 and 2017**.
I heard it's possible with **externalizing targeting parameters**. But i don't know much about it.
Please give me any information about that.

Comment: Can you tell us what error are you getting when you try to run it in vs 2015?

Comment: I would suggest to use [CMake](https://cmake.org/) for this. It will create separate solutions and project files _but_ out of the same project description. (No modification of neither solution nor projects necessary - every update is done by CMake.) As free add-on: CMake simplifies the administration for other platforms as well. If you are not interested in Linux etc. - how about VS with Clang as compiler.

Comment: VS2017 can open and compile the projects for VS2015 without problem. So create solution and project in VS2015 and open it in 2017 without UPGRADNG - and it will use toolchain 140 and be able to work with it in both versions without any problem

Comment: @ Wojtek T it got error like this :-   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(57,5): error MSB8020: The build tools for v141 (Platform Toolset = 'v141') cannot be found. To build using the v141 build tools, please install v141 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".